# Do I need to set up public and private keys for ssh connection

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssh

I have just set up ubuntu server. I want it to act as my git repository for my work. I have installed openssh and have been able to connect by just providing the account password. i.e

```
name@ipaddress
```

which works fine. I have read on some sites that people set up public and private keys in order to secure communication. Not knowing much about ssh, I would like to know: is it necessary for me to do this in order to secure the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it necessary? No.

Is it a good idea? Probably

Having the key instead of a password means that you're no longer susceptible to brute-force attacks for SSH logins. Requiring both is two-factor auth which is even better.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have just created and added my laptops public key to the server. Do I need to add the servers puclic key to my laptop to secure both ways?

Comment: @geminiCoder Not unless you plan on SSHing from your server to your laptop.